# how to send json into kafka using zeebe kafka connector?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, zeebe

I'm trying to send a json into kafka using zeebe kafka connector. zeebe changes the format of json. it replaces colon (:) with equal (=) and replaces double quotation (") with quotation (').

for example:

```json
{ "id": "1234"}
```

changes into

```js
{ 'id'='1234'}
```

but I don't want this transformation happen.how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please clarify with documentation to "Zeebe Kafka Connector" what data format it expects, or will create.